# How to make netbean IDE support both python and php

Tags: php, python, netbeans, ide

netbean IDE support when downloading PHP bundle version. I also found a download of netbean for python. But How can I let one netbean IDE support both PHP and python?

Comment: check this http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download "php" or "all" version here: http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

Install python plugin: http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall

Answer (score 1):

For first download netbeans for php support, and form plugin manager install python support.